Closed form for a finite sum involves $(x^2+\sin^2(j \theta))^{-1/2}$
Suppose that $x\in (0,1)$. Does any one know how to obtain a closed form of the following sum?
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^j\left(x^2+\sin^2 \frac{j\pi}{n}\right)^{-\frac12}$$
Or can you write it in some integral sense?

Using Cauchy's residue theorem, we can rewrite the sum as an integral around the $n$ poles of an appropriate integrand. After rescaling $\frac{j\pi}{n}\mapsto\varphi$, we can write
\begin{align}\tag{1a}\label{eq:1a}
S_n(x)
&\stackrel{\hphantom{e^{\mathrm i\varphi}\mapsto z}}{=}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^j\left(x^2+\sin^2 \frac{j\pi}{n}\right)^{-\frac12} \\
\tag{1b}\label{eq:1b}
&\stackrel{\hphantom{e^{\mathrm i\varphi}\mapsto z}}{=}
\frac{n}{4\pi \, \mathrm i}
\int_{0- \mathrm i 0^+}^{2\pi- \mathrm i 0^+} 
\frac{
 \cot\left(\frac{n \varphi}{2}\right)
-\cot\left(\frac{n \varphi}{2}+\frac \pi 2\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2\varphi}} 
\,\mathrm d \varphi\\
\tag{1c}\label{eq:1c}
&\stackrel{\hphantom{e^{\mathrm i\varphi}\mapsto z}}{=}
\frac{n}{4\pi \, \mathrm i}
\int_{0-\mathrm i 0^+}^{2\pi-\mathrm i 0^+}
\frac{\csc\left({n \varphi}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+\sin^2\varphi}}
\,\mathrm d \varphi\\
\tag{1d}\label{eq:1d}
&\stackrel{e^{\mathrm i\varphi}\mapsto z}{=}
\frac{8n}{\pi}
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1+x^2}-x}
\frac{z^{-1}\,(z^{-n}-z^n)^{-1}}{\sqrt{ (z^{-1}-z)^2-4x^2}}
\,\mathrm d z\\
\tag{1e}\label{eq:1e}
&\stackrel{z\mapsto e^{\phi}}{=}
\frac{2n}{\pi}
\int_{\operatorname{arsinh}x}^{\infty}
\frac{\operatorname{csch}(n\phi)}{\sqrt{\sinh^2\phi-x^2}}
\,\mathrm d \phi\,.
\end{align}
The two cotangents in \eqref{eq:1b} reflect the oscillating summation. In the step to \eqref{eq:1d} we contracted the integration contour from slightly below the real axis/slightly inside the unit circle to go along the square root branch cut. The result can be transformed back to hyperbolic coordinates and is correct for arbitrary $x\in\mathbb R$.
Here is some Mathematica code reflecting the steps:
TableForm@Block[{x=1/10, n=18}, {
N[Sum[(-1)^j/Sqrt[x^2+Sin[j Pi/n]^2],{j,0,n-1}],20],
n/(4 Pi I) NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x^2+Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]^2] (Cot[(\[CurlyPhi] n)/2]-Cot[(\[CurlyPhi] n)/2+Pi/2]), {\[CurlyPhi],0-I/100,2 Pi-I/100},MaxRecursion->100,WorkingPrecision->20],
n/(2 Pi I) NIntegrate[Csc[n \[CurlyPhi]]/Sqrt[x^2+Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]^2], {\[CurlyPhi],0-I/100,2 Pi-I/100}, MaxRecursion->200,WorkingPrecision->20],
8 n/Pi NIntegrate[((z^-n-z^n)^-1)/(z Sqrt[(z^-1-z)^2-4 x^2]), {z,0,Sqrt[1+x^2]-x}, MaxRecursion->100,WorkingPrecision->20],
-8 n/(Pi I) NIntegrate[Csc[n \[CurlyPhi]]/(4 Sqrt[x^2+Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]^2]), {\[CurlyPhi],I ArcSinh[x],I Infinity}, WorkingPrecision->20],
2 n/Pi NIntegrate[Csch[n \[Phi]]/Sqrt[Sinh[\[Phi]]^2-x^2], {\[Phi],ArcSinh[x],Infinity}, WorkingPrecision->20]
}]


Well done! Thanky you!

Can you be more precise on the contour you use? I could not reproduce your proof. Thx.

@Slm2004 The contour runs slightly below the real axis, which transforms to a circle with radius slightly smaller than one, inside the $n$ poles, but around the square root branch cut. I have added a short explanation and some Mathematica code.
